# -job-name and BibTeX do not work together?

Tags: bibtex, jobname

I have a problem using the `%& -job-name=` command together with the bibliography.

If I compile the file without the `-job-name` command, the bibliography appears normally, with that command, instead, I have no bibliography.

By looking into the folder, I have seen that the `.bbl` is not created in the second case.

I am using Texworks with the pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX option. (sorry if this is not the approrpiate name)

MWE:

```
%& -job-name=MWE

\documentclass[english]{scrreprt}

%%% PAGE DIMENSIONS
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{verbose,a4paper,tmargin=3.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.6cm,rmargin=2.6cm,headheight=1.3cm,headsep=1cm}
\pagestyle{headings}

%%% PACKAGES
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{paralist} 
\usepackage{verbatim} 
\usepackage{subfig} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, url}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabu,longtable,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{scrpage2,datetime,tikz}

%%% OPTIONS
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setlength{\parindent}{1em}
\tabulinesep=^1.5mm_1.5mm

%%% DEFINITIONS
\renewcommand{\dateseparator}{.}

\begin{document}

I want to cite \cite{Slotine91}.\\

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{*yourpath*/biblio}

\end{document}
```

And in the `biblio.bib` file I have

```
@book{Slotine91,
  title={Applied nonlinear control},
  author={Slotine, J.J.E. and Li, W. and others},
  year={1991},
  publisher={Prentice-Hall Englewood Cliffs, NJ}
}
```

Does anyone knows what I am doing wrong and/or how I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: BibTeX doesn't know about `-job-name`, so it's run on the inexistent `original.aux` file (where `original.tex` is the name of your file).

Comment: you would need to run `bibtex MWE` rather than `bibtex ..original-file-name...` as that is the name of the generated aux file that bibtex needs to read. You can probably configure your editor to do that but not using `-job-name` is probably an easier option.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I wanted to use it to avoid renaming the file every time I have a different distribution list (each has a different naming convention), but well, seems that I do not have many options. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you would need to run

```
 bibtex MWE
```

rather than

```
bibtex ..original-file-name...
```

as that is the name of the generated aux file that bibtex needs to read. You can probably configure your editor to do that but not using -job-name is probably an easier option.